# Proof that $G/H_1$ is isomorphic to $G/H_2$ when $H_1$ and $H_2$ are normal groups of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $H_1$ and $H_2$ be normal subgroups of a group $G$. I want to show, that $G/H_1$ is isomorphic to $G/H_2$ when $H_1$ and $H_2$ are normal groups. Why $H_1$ and $H_2$ should be conjugate subgroup to be true? Can you give a example???

I see the next proof of Martin Brandenburg:

If $\phi : G/H_1 \to G/H_2$ is a homomorphism of $G$-sets, and $\phi([1])=[g]$, then it follows more generally that $\phi([x])=[xg]$. But $\phi$ should be well-defined, i.e. $y^{-1} x \in H_1$ implies $(y g)^{-1} x g \in H_2$. This reduces to $g^{-1} H_1 g \subseteq H_2$. Conversely, this relation implies that $\phi([x]):=[xg]$ is a well-defined homomorphism of $G$-sets.  Similarly, $\phi$ is injective iff $g H_2 g^{-1} \subseteq H_1$. And $\phi$ is automatically surjective. It follows that $G/H_1 \cong G/H_2$ as $G$-sets iff $H_1$ and $H_2$ are conjugated.

Why do you suppose they are homomorphic?

Why $\phi$ is inyective and surjective at the same time?

Can you write me an example with $\mathbb{Z}_n\times\mathbb{Z}_m$ with n and m integer value?

Thanks for your help,

Comment: End of the first sentence: "when $H_1$ and $H_2$" what?

Comment: Probably I'm misunderstanding something, but how can two *different* normal subgroups be conjugated? That sounds like a straightforward contradiction...

Comment: The question's intent is a little hard to decipher, but for one thing, you can't have a non-trivial example with $G$ Abelian, since conjugate subgroups of an Abelian group are identical.

Comment: Good morning, thanks for you comments. I need to know if $G/H_1$ and $G/H_2$ is isomorphic iff $H_1$, $H_2$ are conjugated

Comment: I think this question is being misunderstood because, in the title and the first paragraph, one is led to think that the notation $G/H$ refers to a quotient group. Only in the third paragraph does it become clear that it's intended to refer to a $G$-set.

Comment: The $G$-sets $G/H_1$ and $G/H_2$ are isomorphic if and only if $H_1$ and $H_2$ are conjugate in $G$.  Since the title and the first paragraph of your question refer to *normal* subgroups, I should repeat what was said in earlier comments: The only way $H_1$ and $H_2$ can be conjugate if at least one of them is normal in $G$ is for them to be equal.  But the first sentence of this comment is true for any subgroups, normal or not.

Comment: I agree with Andreas, and this is beyond the fact that $\;G/H_i\;$ refers to a "set" and not to a quotient group: it is *clearly* said "normal subgroups" and conjugated. In my opinion that's impossible in any case *unless* $\;H_1=H_2\;$

Comment: Then two normal subgroups cant be conjugated... Well, it means that  "The G-sets $G/H_1$ and $G/H_2$ are isomorphic if and only if $H_1$ and $H_2$ are conjugate in $G$" when $H_1$ or $H_2$ arent normal, or one of them is normal, but not both can be normal...